# Solidity - "Failed to decode output: Error: hex data is odd-length (argument=\"value\", value=\"0x0\", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.7.0)"

Tags: solidity

I used these functions for my TicTacToe contract but it gives an error. This contract uses Minimax algorithm to find optimal way to play against a player. I have to use makeMoveY function inside the function when player uses to make a move. (When the player makes the move, makeMoveY function will be executed and computer will counter-play.)

My functions are below:

```
  function makeMove(
        uint256 _gameID,
        uint256 _xCoordinate,
        uint256 _yCoordinate
    ) public returns (bool success, string memory reason) {
        if (_gameID > nrOfGames) return (false, "No such game exists.");

        Game storage game = games[_gameID - 1];

        if (game.winner != Winners.None)
            return (false, "The game has already ended.");

        if (msg.sender != getCurrentPlayer(game))
            return (false, "It is not your turn.");

        if (game.board[_xCoordinate][_yCoordinate] != Players.None)
            return (false, "There is already a mark at the given coordinates.");

        game.board[_xCoordinate][_yCoordinate] = game.playerTurn;

        emit PlayerMadeMove(_gameID, msg.sender, _xCoordinate, _yCoordinate);

        Winners winner = calculateWinner(game.board);
        if (winner != Winners.None) {
            game.winner = winner;
            emit GameOver(_gameID, winner);

            return (true, "The game is over.");
        }

        nextPlayer(game);

        if (game.gameType == GameType.PlayerVsComputer) {
            makeMoveY(game, game.board);
            return (true, "Computer played. Your turn again");
        }

        return (true, "");
    }

    function MiniMax(
        Players[3][3] storage _board,
        uint256 _depth,
        bool _isMax
    ) private returns (int256) {
        if (calculateWinner(_board) == Winners.PlayerOne) return 10;
        if (calculateWinner(_board) == Winners.PlayerTwo) return -10;

        if (isBoardFull(_board)) return 0;

        int256 best;

        if (_isMax) {
            best = -1000;

            for (uint8 i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (uint8 j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    if (_board[i][j] == Players.None){
                            _board[i][j] == Players.PlayerOne;
                            best = max(best, MiniMax(_board, _depth + 1, !_isMax));
                            _board[i][j] = Players.None;
                    }
                }
            }
            return best;
        } else {
            best = 1000;

            for (uint8 i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (uint8 j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    if (_board[i][j] == Players.None)
                        {
                            _board[i][j] == Players.PlayerTwo;
                            best = min(best, MiniMax(_board, _depth + 1, !_isMax));
                            _board[i][j] = Players.None;
                        }
                }
            }
            return best;
        }
    }
     
    function findBestMoveY(Players[3][3] storage _board)
        private
        returns (uint8[2] memory)
    {
        int256 bestVal = 1000;
        int256 moveVal;
        uint8[2] memory bestMove;

        for (uint8 i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (uint8 j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (_board[i][j] == Players.None) {
                    _board[i][j] = Players.PlayerTwo;

                    moveVal = MiniMax(_board, 0, true);

                    _board[i][j] = Players.None;

                    if (moveVal < bestVal) {
                        bestMove[0] = i;
                        bestMove[1] = j;
                        bestVal = moveVal;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return bestMove;
    }

    function makeMoveY(Game storage _game, Players[3][3] storage _board)
        private
        returns (bool success, string memory reason)
    {
        if (_game.playerTurn != Players.PlayerTwo)
            return (false, "Not second players turn");
        uint8[2] memory move = findBestMoveY(_board);
        _board[move[0]][move[1]] = Players.PlayerTwo;
        nextPlayer(_game);
        return (true, "");
    }
```

Error line:

```
    "error": "Failed to decode output: Error: hex data is odd-length (argument=\"value\", value=\"0x0\", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.7.0)"
```

I am a newbie here, so I might have skipped any information. Please let me know if I am missing anything that you should have. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Somewhere there is a string "0x0" where hex is expected like "00" or "4C656T". Probably in some settings file. Every byte is presented as 2 hexadecimal characters, hence the even test.

Comment: I concluded that the error was caused by the recursion that I used in the MiniMax function, but I still cannot understand why it caused an error. Can you look into that, please? @JoopEggen

Comment: I nowhere see either "value" or "0x0". So it does not seem to be the algorithm. You can comment out code, till the moment happens that that specific error disappears. I cannot help. Good luck.